# Cannot update default value on Two-Way data bindings

Tags: backbone.js

I have use Backbone on my project. But when I try to use Two-Way data bindings on my view, I cannot update the default value when user change the binded text field. Below is my sample code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            "val_one": "1",
            "val_two": "2"
        }
    });

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.model = this.model || new MyModel();

    this.viewModel = {
        val_one: ko.observable(this.model.get('val_one')),
        val_two: ko.observable(this.model.get('val_two'))
    }

    this.viewModel.val_one.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.model.set({val_one:newValue});
    });

    this.viewModel.val_two.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        var nNumber = parseInt(newValue) + parseInt(self.model.get('val_one'));
        self.model.set({val_two:nNumber});
    });

    this.model.on("change", function() {
      console.log("Model changed");

      //you can do whatever you want with your model now
      //e.g sync it with the server, update parts of your
      //view, etc
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.model.attributes, function(val, key) { 
        var row = "<tr><td><input type='text' data-bind='value: " + key + "' /></td><td><p data-bind='text: " + key + "'>0</p></td></tr>";
        $('#mytable').append(row);
    });

    ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel);
  }
});

function UpdateView(){
    var newModel = new MyModel();
    var modelView = new MyView({model: newModel});
    modelView.render();
}

UpdateView();

});
```

I have wrote this line of code: `var nNumber = parseInt(newValue) + parseInt(self.model.get('val_one'));`. So whenever user update text field, the default value should update so. But the label isn't updated with new number.

So I want the new number should be replaced in the label next to the text field. Please look at the picture:

[image]

Regards,

Comment: *"when I try to use Two-Way data bindings on my view"* - Please explain how you are trying to achieve this. What is `ko`..? Can you create an [mcve]  becuase we don't even know what libraries you're using .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple EventManager created for 2-way binding. Feel free to use it.

```
define(['underscore','backbone'], function (_, Backbone) {
"use strict";

var EventManager,
    wrapperCallback,
    triggerParams,
    receiverName,
    senderObj;

EventManager = function () {

    this.bind = function (sender, receiver, eventName, callback, clearAll, senderName) {

        wrapperCallback = this.getWrapperCallback(receiver, eventName, senderName, callback);

        if (clearAll === true) {
            sender.unbind(eventName);
        } else {
            sender.unbind(eventName, wrapperCallback);
        }

        console.log("Bind " + receiverName + " on " + senderName + "." + eventName);

        sender.bind(eventName, wrapperCallback, receiver);
    };

    this.trigger = function (sender, eventName, data) {

        console.log("Trigger Event: " + eventName);
        senderObj = sender;
        [].splice.call(arguments, 0, 1);
        senderObj.trigger.apply(senderObj, arguments);
    };

    this.getWrapperCallback = function (receiver, eventName, senderName, callback) {
        function wrapperFunction(params) {

            console.log("Received Event: " + eventName + " from " + senderName);

            callback.apply(receiver, arguments);
        }

        return wrapperFunction;
    };

};

return new EventManager();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

BackboneJs doesn't have a two way data binding, you need to implement it yourself by using event listeners, in your case use the onkeyup event listener to connect the view and the model

Comment: Could you please explain your idea clearer? How can an event be added to the input field? And what function will it call to update the model and view?